# Java Choice Menu Difficulties, Colour and Draw_Line

Tags: java, colors, applet, awt, draw

I'm trying to create a MS Paint-like software with Java Choice Menus, but I'm experiencing some difficulties with two functions in particular

1. I get a massive wall of error text upon selecting a colour from my Colour Menu. What I wish to achieve is selecting the colour converts the string containing the option into lower case, before setting the PenColour into that option
2. Drawing Lines don't seem to work, despite the same code being functional in a different applet that didn't use Choice. I want it to select two points which then have a line drawn between them.

Here is my Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.Choice;

public class PockettProjectTest1 extends Applet implements ActionListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
//Coordinates and sizes used to draw GUI
    private final int GUI_HEIGHT = 100;
    private final int GUI_START_X = 10;
    private final int GUI_START_Y = 10;
    private final int FIELD_SIZE = 11; //Numbers of characters for text field display
////////////////////////GLOBAL VARIABLES////////////////////////
    private Dimension appletSize; //used to encapsulate the Applets dimensions
    private int x, y, appletHeight, appletWidth, PenThick, PenMode, ShapeMode, ClickXO, ClickYO, ClickXN, ClickYN, ClickCount;
    private String SizeString; 
//a Panel is a container used here to hold and position the GUI components
    private Panel guiPanel;
    private Color PenColour;
//GUI components cv
    public void init(){
        //Disables the applet layout manager and stops automatic GUI component positioning
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.white);
        addMouseListener(this);  
        addMouseMotionListener(this);  
        addMouseListener(this);  
        ClickCount = 0;
        ClickXO = 0;
        ClickYO = 0;
        ClickXN = 0;
        ClickYN = 0;
        PenMode = 0;
        ShapeMode = 0;
        appletSize = this.getSize(); //captures the Applet dimensions
        appletHeight = appletSize.height; //captures the Applet height
        appletWidth = appletSize.width; //captures the Applet width
        //Set up the Panel ready to hold the GUI components
        guiPanel = new Panel();
        guiPanel.setLocation(0, 0);
        guiPanel.setSize(appletWidth,GUI_HEIGHT);
        guiPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 40));
        guiPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        add(guiPanel);

        Choice mode = new Choice();
        Choice size = new Choice();
        Choice color = new Choice();
        Choice shape = new Choice();
         
         mode.add("Pen");
         mode.add("Eraser");
         mode.add("Fill");
         mode.add("Shape");
         
         size.add("01px");
         size.add("02px");
         size.add("03px");
         size.add("05px");
         size.add("10px");
         size.add("15px");
         size.add("20px");
         size.add("30px");
         size.add("50px");
         
         
         shape.add("N/A");
         shape.add("Line");
         shape.add("Oval");
         shape.add("Oblong");
         shape.add("Square");
         shape.add("Circle");
         shape.add("FillOval");
         shape.add("FillOblong");
         shape.add("FillSquare");
         shape.add("FillCircle");
         //add choice or combobox
         guiPanel.add(mode);
         guiPanel.add(size);
         guiPanel.add(shape);
         PenThick = 1;
         PenColour = Color.black;
 
    mode.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie)
        {
        PenMode = mode.getSelectedIndex();
        
        }
    });
    
     size.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie)
        {
        SizeString = size.getSelectedItem();
        PenThick = Integer.parseInt(SizeString.substring(0,2));
        Graphics g = getGraphics();  
        
        }
    });
//// Start of Issue 1:
         colour.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie)
        {
        ColourString = colour.getSelectedItem();
        ColourString.toLowerCase();
        Color PenColour.getColor(ColourString);
        }
    });
    /// End of Issue 1
     shape.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie)
        {
        ShapeMode = shape.getSelectedIndex();
        }
    });
    
    
}
        
        
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
    }
    ////Issue 2:
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me){  
    if (PenMode == 3) {
    if (ClickCount == 0) {
    ClickXO = me.getX();
    ClickYO = me.getY();
    ClickCount ++;
    System.out.println(ClickCount);
    return;
    }
    if (ClickCount == 1) {
    ClickXN = me.getX();
    ClickYN = me.getY();    
    System.out.println(ClickCount);
    Graphics g = getGraphics();  
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawLine(ClickXO, ClickYO, ClickXN, ClickYN);
    System.out.println(ClickXO);
    System.out.println(ClickYO);
    System.out.println(ClickXN);
    System.out.println(ClickYN);
    ClickCount = 0; 
    }
    }
        
}
/// End of Issue 2
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    }
    
    
    
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){  
        if (PenMode == 0){
        Graphics g = getGraphics();  
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillOval(e.getX(), e.getY(), PenThick, PenThick);  
        }
        if (PenMode == 1){
        Graphics g = getGraphics();  
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(e.getX(), e.getY(), PenThick, PenThick);  
        }
        
}
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
}  
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
}  
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
}  
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
}   
}
```

I have to have this code due by the end of Friday, so I hope I can get the issue solved by then.

Comment: *"I hope I can get the issue solved by then."* This is a Q&A site rather than a 'problem solving forum'. It works best as a searchable repository of questions (I don't see a question above) with accepted answers. To work best in that capacity, each Q&A needs to focus on a ***single*** *question* with a descriptive title. Please [edit] 1 question into the above, and move the other problem to another (appropriately titled) thread. BTW: 1) Applets and AWT. One is deprecated, the other 15 years out of relevance.  Drop both, and any course where they have not updated their teaching materials. ..

Comment: .. to suit 'modern times'. *"I have to have this code due by the end of Friday, so I hope.."* Don't add things like that to questions. It implies you want the reader to devote more time to your problem than what they might dedicate to someone with good time-management skills. I'll help the person with good time-management skills any day. Many others are the same.

Comment: 1) *I get a massive wall of error text* - We are not mind readers we can't guess what the error is. What you are referring to is the stack trace. It tells your the error and the statement causing the error. So read the trace, find the statement causing the problem and then fix the issue. 2) variable names should not start with an upper case character. Some of your variable are correct. Others are not. Be consistent!!!